# JQuery - Loop through 700 and more Elements

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I've already asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873248/jquery-maptiles-loading-very-slow-with-lazy-load), but nobody was able to help.

I would like to try it with a theoretical question first now:

I have about 7xx - 15xx HTML elements in a moveable div and a viewport (lets say 1000px+500px).

I can drag the div with those elements within this viewport and when an element comes into the viewport, it loads an image.

So with every drag, jQuery has to check if the element is in the viewport or not.

The problem I'm coming across is that this is really laggy (except in Chrome) and I do not know why.  With 300 elements everything works fine.

Is it just too much for jQuery to handle?

function LoadImage() {

```
var images = $(".emptyTile");
//console.log(images);

//Viewport data
var inview = images.filter(function() {   
    var top =       m.viewingBox.offset().top -200;
    var left =      m.viewingBox.offset().left -200;
    var right =     m.viewingBox.offset().left + m.viewingBox.width() +200;
    var bot =       m.viewingBox.offset().top + m.viewingBox.height() +200;

    //Image data
    var imgT = $(this).offset().top;
    var imgL = $(this).offset().left;
    var imgR = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
    var imgB = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();             

    //check borders of viewport
    return (imgB > top && imgR > left && imgL < right && imgT < bot)
});

images.one("loadIt", function() {
    source = $(this).attr("data-src");

    if (source) {
        $(this).attr("src", source);
        $(this).attr("class", "fullTile");
    }
});

loaded = inview.trigger("loadIt");
images = images.not(loaded);
```

}

This is emptyFile before triggering the switch:

```
<img class="emptyTile" data-src="images/map3/map673.png" src="images/loading.gif">
```

And after:

```
<img class="emptyTile" data-src="images/map3/map673.png" src="images/map3/map673.png">
```

Comment: Rethink the project. Are you sure you want to drag 700+ element at once? Why not just a reference?

Comment: The question is very very vague!

Comment: Hard to tell without your code.. There is probably an inefficiency in your algorithm though. I have a feature with 25000 elements (client wanted an "all history" button) and it has live filter as you type. There isn't much lag. I can't see 700 elements being that rough.

Comment: Got any code? There's no real way we can help you if you can't demonstrate your problem.

Comment: not enough context ... provide some of your code.

Comment: Adding the code. sorry, that i forgot the basic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it just too much for JQuery to handle?

Not quite.  When you see lag, you're more likely coming across is limitations in the browser itself rather than in jQuery.

In your situation, it's most likely that inefficiencies in your code are the root cause although without seeing your actual code there's nothing more any of us can really do to help you.

I, as others, have worked on far bigger element-sets than that without lag.